# Why do I have 40000 packages in my Angular 7 project ? How to remove unused dependencies?

Tags: angular, npm, angular7, package.json

When launching `npm audit` in my console, I have the following output :

`[...]
found 0 vulnerabilities in 40256 scanned packages`

Why do I have 40000+ packages in my project ? This amount of packages seems insane to me, as I don't use this much libraries.

I've tried the following :

- Removing unused packages (Jasmine, Karma, ...).
- Using `npm prune`.

I found out that it's mainly due to Angular7's dependencies :

- When downgrading to Angular 5, I "only" have ~7000 packages.
- My `package.lock.json` file is almost 10000 lines long, and a lot of these are dependencies.

It bothers me because of these reasons :

- Having this much packages can bring frequent security issues.
- Launching `npm install` needs more resources and time, and I would like to optimise it more.
- I have a lot of unused packages that have nothing to do here (e.g I don't need some polyfills that are present, like Babel, as I don't want to develop a cross-browser solution).

Is it a bad idea to remove these unused packages ?

Why is there so many packages in a freshly created Angular 7 project ?

How do I remove unused Angular's dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely remove the packages but a good idea would be to keep it.

Reason: We won't be knowing what package is using what other dependent package. So it is better not to remove it.

But don't worry. Before deploying, once you run `ng build` it will automatically remove the unused packages.